# C# Metro Progress Bar to Circle

Tags: c#, user-interface, progress-bar, microsoft-metro

I need to make circle with bar.

Here is my image when someone will still not understand:
[image: My image]

Does any existing control work? Or should I create a new control somehow? I used a new control with circle filled with gradient but it isn't the same effect :(

I also tried to draw a circle but when I do in my math cycle with sin and cos it does something what I do not want.

```
        double slice = 2 * Math.PI / 360;

        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        {
            double angle = slice * i;

            int x = (int)(0 + 300 * Math.Cos(angle)); // start x + radius * ...
            int y = (int)(0 + 300 * Math.Sin(angle));

            Line line = new Line()
            {
                X1 = 0,
                Y1 = 0,

                X2 = x,
                Y2 = y,

                Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
                StrokeThickness = 1.0
            };

            canvas.Children.Add(line);
        }
```

EDIT: Metro = Xaml!!!

Comment: I love your image ! (Ms paint forever)

Comment: Windows Forms? Wpf? Silverlight?

Comment: I am not sure about a solid circle, but I know Telerik has wpf, winform, AND silverlight controls for the metro load bar, which is the dots moving around in a circle.

Comment: But i dont want dots :( And Telerik isnt free

Comment: Has anybody skill to rewrite http://davidpallmann.blogspot.cz/2012/08/adventures-in-windows-8-timer-metro-app.html from Javascript to C#?